# I´m trying to filter data of colums from a Data Frame, but the index names contain white spaces

Tags: python, pandas, filter, row, spaces

I`m trying to filter the rows of a Data Frame, but since the index name of the column has white spaces, I've not been able to do it

The DDTS Number is the name of the column

It worked when there is no spaces

data[data3.(DDTS Number) != null]

I've tried different syntax but I don't if there is way to do it without to rename the column name

Comment: can you show what you get when you run the following `df..index.unique()`

Comment: Hi @Jeril here the output:                                                                      data3["DDTS Number"].unique()                                                               array([nan, 'CSCti75606', 'CSCuz03742', 'CSCur46663', 'CSCvc99542',
       'CSCur18489', 'CSCvc60471', 'CSCvf65345', 'CSCux60676'],
      dtype=object)

Comment: you mentioned in the question that the index has a white space, so can you show what you get when you run the following `df.index.unique()`

Answer (score 0):

Hi everyone I found the solution. The problem with the method I used was it did not work when the index had spaces in the name so there is another way to get rid of the null values using the following structure:

df1 = df[df["ColumnName With Spaces"].notnull()]

From here you will filter all the rows in the "df" with index "ColumnName With Spaces" thet contain null values.